# FXML: ImageViews showing up in SceneBuilder but not in the actual app

Tags: java, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm trying to write a simple Java app for modifying and visualizing logic circuits by dragging gates and connections about. I'm using SceneBuilder to put the interface together. Right now, I'm stuck at getting the available basic logic gates to display in their proper bar and respond to being interacted with. More accurately, I'm trying to get one gate to just display some console output, to confirm that the GUI-logic connection is working.

The biggest problem I'm having is that the ImageViews of the gates, possibly along with some other FXML elements, refuse to display in the actual compiled app for some reason, even though they work and react correctly in SceneBuilder and in its "Preview" feature.

I had to do some experimenting with wrapping them in various other FXML elements which I didn't really understand because apparently ImageWiew doesn't have a onDragDetected() method, even though the text input field for it is available in SceneBuilder. The intended work-in-progress app layout can be seen plainly enough directly from SceneBuilder on the first picture. Compare with the second one, which is of the actual running application.

[image: As seen in SceneBuilder]
[image: GUI of the running app]

Possibly relevant code:

Main.java

```
package main;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Main extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("RootLayout.fxml"));
            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 640, 450));
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

TheCircuitController.java

```
package Gates;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


/**
 * The class for holding all the information about gates, connections, and in and out pins in the current circuit
 */
public class TheCircuitController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchorPaneNAND;

    //TODO temporarily public, make private later
    public ArrayList<CircuitElement> allCircuitElements= new ArrayList<CircuitElement>();
    public ArrayList<Pin> theCircuitInputPins = new ArrayList<Pin>();
    public ArrayList<Pin> theCircuitOutputPins = new ArrayList<Pin>();
    ArrayList<Connection> allCircuitConnections = new ArrayList<Connection>();
    public ArrayList<Pin> allCircuitGateInputPins = new ArrayList<Pin>();
    public ArrayList<Pin> allCircuitGateOutputPins = new ArrayList<Pin>();
    public ArrayList<Gate> allCircuitGates = new ArrayList<Gate>();

    private InbuiltGateType currentDragGateType;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // initialize your logic here: all @FXML variables will have been injected
        anchorPaneNAND.setOnDragDetected(this::handleDragDetectedNAND);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleDragDetectedNAND(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        System.out.println("drag detected nand!");
    }

//other stuff of the class, unrelated to FXML
}
```

RootLayout.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Gates.TheCircuitController">
   <children>
      <MenuBar prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="562.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.2413793103448276" prefHeight="402.0" prefWidth="640.0">
         <items>
            <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="122.0">
               <content>
                  <VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="208.0" spacing="10.0">
                     <children>
                        <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPaneNAND" onDragDetected="#handleDragDetectedNAND">
                           <children>
                              <ImageView>
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@../../resources/100px-NAND_ANSI.svg.png" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                        <ImageView>
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@../../resources/100px-NOT_ANSI.svg.png" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
                        <ImageView>
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@../../resources/100px-AND_ANSI.svg.png" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
                        <ImageView>
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@../../resources/OR_ANSI.svg.png" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
                        <ImageView>
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@../../resources/100px-NOR_ANSI.svg.png" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
                        <ImageView>
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@../../resources/100px-XOR_ANSI.svg.png" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
                        <ImageView>
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@../../resources/100px-XNOR_ANSI.svg.png" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
                     </children>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets left="20.0" right="20.0" />
                     </padding></VBox>
               </content></ScrollPane>
            <ScrollPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="406.0" />
         </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

I thus need to know:

Why are those gates(or at least one) not displaying as intended? And what's with the ScrollPane, why is it not displaying its sliders as it is in SceneBuilder? What things do I need to set up differently or wiggle with to get those gates to show up and interact correctly?

Comment: The best way to check if the scene-graph has been built correctly is to use http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/. If the ScrollPane and the VBox are there check the height values. It also depends on how you built your application. It can happen hat the images are not in the right place after building

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of random crapshooting, I found a solution.

First, I looked into `View->Show Sample Controller Skeleton`. There, I noticed that the `handleDragDetectedNAND()` method does not have any modifier, whereas mine had `private`, copied early from some tutorial or the other. I removed the modifier and the application now works. If anyone who passes by cared to explain why this is the case(I have no idea and no time to research, deadline's fast approaching), the value of this answer would rise significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure all images **inside** of `src` folder. (**tested**)

> The image which outsite of `src` folder dont appear.

```
+ MyProject
  + not_working_dir
  + src
    + com.stackoverflow
    + working_dir
```